How to define RabbitMQ queue using spring-cloud-streams without a listener
I need to set the exchange and queue for RabbitMQ in my Spring Boot application, the thing is, The application only acts as a producer, but I need to define de queue as well in the service.
steps that I did:

set the @Input and @Output for my Queue and exchange.
Define the bindings in application.yml (spring.cloud.stream.bindings and binders)
develop the code to send the message using the @output method

When I run the application, the queue and exchange are in my RabbitMQ container, but when a message is received in the queue I have this error in my application:
Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Is it possible to set a queue using spring cloud stream without a listener? Only set the binding to set the queue in RabbitMQ
The spring cloud stream versions used is: 3.2.10
It's an old customer project.
Thanks in advance!

You must be using a very old version of spring-cloud-stream as @Input and @Output has log been deprecated and removed. Please read this section of the manual and feel free to follow up with more question https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/programming-model.html

Thanks for your answer @OlegZhurakousky . Yes, I know, it's an old project that the customer has not updated yet. Intellij told me about this as well.

Well, it's no longer supported so I am not sure what else I can add as there is no code that corresponds to what you are asking about

Maybe if it's possible to set a queue in the service without listener. just to create the queue in RabbitMQ using the service??

This is not what spring-cloud-stream is designed for. Consider looking at spring-amqp project
